# The name of this metric.

Tags: differential-geometry

Does anyone know  what metric is the following one in $\mathbb{R}^n$?
$g=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(1+x_i^2)dx_i^2+2\sum_{i\neq j}x_i x_j dx_i dx_j$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's the Euclidean metric tensor written for the sumbanifold, the quadric surface $x_{n+1}= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2$, induced by the ambient metric in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, $g=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}dx_i^2$.